# Projection of 4D geodesic in spacetime onto 3D space is an ellipse

Tags: general-relativity

In the Wikipedia article on "Geodesics in general relativity" we can find the following statement:

> In general relativity, gravity can be regarded as not a force but a
>   consequence of a curved spacetime geometry where the source of
>   curvature is the stress–energy tensor (representing matter, for
>   instance). **Thus, for example, the path of a planet orbiting a star is
>   the projection of a geodesic of the curved four-dimensional (4-D)
>   spacetime geometry around the star onto three-dimensional (3-D) space.**

Now, I take the last sentence to mean that, for example, the orbit of the earth around the sun appears to us as elliptical because with our eyes we can only perceive space as being three-dimensional. That is we can only perceive the curvature of spacetime indirectly. However, can this statement be made mathematically precise? Can we calculate a geodesic for this situation and show that its projection into three dimensions is an ellipse (maybe by choosing coordinates in such a way that the 3d orbit is embedded in a 2d plane)? When we want to project a great circle of the unit sphere $S^3 \subset \mathbb{R}^4$ onto a hyperplane $H \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ there's not really a natural choice for this hyperplane. So in this case we cannot speak of "the" projection of the geodesic onto three-dimensional space. Is the situation in general relativity somehow different? Is there a natural choice in this situation? If this can be found in a textbook I'm of course happy for a pointer. I'm a mathematics graduate student with a background in differential geometry but have not studied any GR yet.

**EDIT:** In response to comments I feel the need to clarify the question maybe a bit more. The point of my question is not to which extent earths orbit is elliptical (which is an interesting question in itself, but not what I intended to ask). For all I care it can be perfectly circular. Above I highlighted a sentence from Wikipedia and I want to know if the statement can be made mathematically precise. Let me explain what I mean by this. Let's start with the geodesic equation from GR:
$$ {d^{2}x^{\mu } \over ds^{2}}+\Gamma ^{\mu }{}_{\alpha \beta }{dx^{\alpha } \over ds}{dx^{\beta } \over ds}=0\ $$
A geodesic in spacetime $M$ (i.e. a four-dimensional, smooth, connected Lorentzian manifold) is a solution curve $\gamma:[a,b]\to M$ to this equation. As far as I understand it, the most basic model for a curved spacetime in the vicinity of a central fixed mass is given by the Schwarzschild metric. So we can probably neglect the mass of a planet placed nearby this central mass and just solve the geodesic equations using the Schwarzschild metric. As has been noted in the comments we would expect this planet to have a helical worldline (if its orbit in space is confined to a fixed 2d plane). I'd love to see a derivation of a geodesic from the equation above, such that we can see that the resulting curve is tracing out a 3d helix of some sort. So the final result of the calculation would be something like $$\gamma(t) = (t, \cos(t), \sin(t), 0).$$

Comment: See first diagram [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theoretical_motivation_for_general_relativity). The elliptical projection precesses slightly. The scale is way off. Basically it’s a vertical line with some tiny wobbles.

Comment: Thanks for the link and the diagram. But I was hoping for an actual calculation, i.e. solving the geodesic equation for a test particle (e.g. earth) in the vicinity of a massive object (the sun) and then showing that the resulting spacetime curve can be projected into 3-space (in some meaningful way) to give a elliptical/circular orbit. So starting with the geodesic equation and in the end I would expect we get something like $x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1$ (with a suitable choice of coordinates). Maybe I just don't get the explanation in your linked Wikipedia article...

Comment: FWIW, in reference to the helix diagram linked by G. Smith, for Earth's worldline (in the rest frame of the Sun), the diameter of the helix is about 1000 (light) seconds, and the vertical distance from one loop to the next is ~31.5 million seconds. So there's only a very small deviation from a perfectly vertical worldline.